# wifi adaptor not found - realtek RTL8852BE in ubuntu 22.10

Tags: wireless

I tried all the posted answers for Ubuntu 22.04. None of them works. Is there any updated solution to make this wifi card work on 22.10?

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
    Kernel modules: rtw_8852be
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: KIOXIA Corporation Device [1e0f:000c]

sudo dmesg | grep 8852
[    0.548852] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C005: Found 3 idle states
[    2.264101] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[    2.267167] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_fw.bin
[    2.268639] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_config.bin
[    2.286661] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw89/rtw8852b_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    2.286668] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: failed to early request firmware: -2
[    2.287095] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.287141] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw89/rtw8852b_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    2.287144] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: failed to request firmware
[    2.293816] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[    2.293851] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip information
[    2.294863] rtw89_8852be: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -22
```

Further followup:After running the codes including the firmware version

```
sudo dmesg | grep 8852

[    2.248613] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[    2.250594] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_fw.bin
[    2.251694] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_config.bin
[    2.338538] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.353915] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 67.84.89.80, cmd version 62, type 1
[    2.358189] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]invalid fw dynamic header len
[    2.358229] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: parse fw header fail
[    2.358249] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fwdl 0x1E0 = 0x1
[    2.358266] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fwdl 0x83F2 = 0x0
[    2.358290] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358325] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358355] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358385] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358418] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358456] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358485] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358516] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358547] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358579] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358608] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358642] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900394
[    2.358671] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358699] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.358727] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb89003d8
[    2.358756] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip information
[    2.359920] rtw89_8852be: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -22
```

***UPDATE 2:***

```
sudo dmesg | grep -e 8852 -e rtw
```

```
[    1.088521] nvme nvme0: allocated 64 MiB host memory buffer.
[    2.206277] rtw89core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.206547] rtw89core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.280825] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.287852] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 67.84.89.80, cmd version 62, type 1
[    2.287860] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: MAC has already powered on
[    2.293461] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]invalid fw dynamic header len
[    2.293473] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: parse fw header fail
[    2.293485] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fwdl 0x1E0 = 0x1
[    2.293495] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fwdl 0x83F2 = 0x0
[    2.293509] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb89002ec
[    2.293530] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293551] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293571] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293592] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293613] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293633] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293654] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293675] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900394
[    2.293696] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293716] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb890038c
[    2.293737] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293758] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293779] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293799] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8900384
[    2.293819] rtw89_8852be 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip information
[    2.298531] rtw89_8852be: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -22
[    2.309648] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[    2.312201] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_fw.bin
[    2.312942] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_config.bin
```

Comment: What command is producing this error? Nothing in your question accounts for this message.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
cd rtw89
git checkout bea0ed7
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw_8852be
```

I also see:

> warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
> The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu
> 12.2.0-3ubuntu1) 12.2.0   You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1) 12.2.0

Notice that the versions are actually the same, 12.2.0-3ubuntu1, and that this is a warning, not an error.

**EDIT 1**: Firmware is required. From the terminal:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtw89/rtw8852b_fw.bin
sudo modprobe -r rtw_8852be && sudo modprobe rtw_8852be
```

Your wireless should now be working.

**EDIT 2**: I notice that there have been recent changes at the git repository; I suspect that the inability to compile the driver on kernels 5.19+ was addressed. I was able to compile the driver on my own 5.19 system without error.

Please do:

```
sudo rm -r rtw89
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot. Post any errors and also:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -e 8852 -e rtw
```

Comment: This returned me with "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw_8852be': Key was rejected by service"

Comment: @Hrushi do you have secure boot on?

Comment: No, I have turned it off

Comment: I retried this after a restart, it didn't return me with any error. But, still it says that no wifi adapter found.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep 8852`

Comment: Yes, updated the question

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Still nothing, same message "No wifi adapter found"

Comment: Basically, nothing is returned after I run the last command. I rebooted the systems and retried.

Comment: How about: `sudo dmesg | grep 8852`

Comment: I have added this in my question

Comment: See my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: Let's see: `modprobe -c | grep B852` and also: `lsmod | grep 8852`